# Cannot use git command, get no such file error

Tags: git

When I try to use git (even just typing `git`, `git clone <repo>`, etc, I get this error:

```
bash: /usr/games/git: No such file or directory
```

but git works with `sudo` just fine.

`which -a git` returns `/usr/bin/git`

Why is it looking in the wrong place, and `/usr/bin/games` of all places?

How can I change where it looks?

Comment: What's the output of `command -v git`?

Comment: It says `/usr/bin/git`

Comment: And `file /usr/bin/git`?

Comment: `/usr/bin/git: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=cc2ef87a752fd09905966dd11aee96ea5214d16a, stripped`

Comment: Nevermind, it was because I had used Open in Terminal into / instead of ~. Sorry to waste your time!

Comment: Still doesn't make sense, though. O.o

Comment: Did some more digging... Turns out gargoyle (runs Inform 7 games) takes over the `git` command. I uninstalled it and git, then installed git first before installing gargoyle and it worked. So, I guess that's why.